# Microsoft Core Audio API: Getting WAVEFORMATEX info from default endpoint

Tags: c++, audio, apimonitor

I am studying the interaction between a game's audio engine and Microsoft Core Audio APIs that are called. I am trying to figure out, how the game got the 'WAVEFORMATEX' info from the default endpoint. I see that at a point during game start, IsFormatSupported() [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370876(v=vs.85).aspx] is called with the *pFormat (second parameter of IsFormatSupported) populated with format information of the default endpoint (i.e. channels, bitspersample, sampling rate etc.). I also see that the game had not called GetMixFormat() [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370872(v=vs.85).aspx] prior to this.

However, there are a series of calls related to IMMDeviceEnumerator (EnumAudioEndpoints, QuryInterface, AddRef, etc.), IMMDeviceCollection (GetCount, Item) and IMMDevice (QueryInterface, AddRef, etc.). Looking at the documentation for these, there doesn't appear to be a direct way of deriving the 'format' (WAVEFORMATEX) information. While, MMDevice::OpenPropertyStore() is called and subsequently 'GetId()', I don't see a call to 'GetValue()' with 'PKEY_AudioEngine_DeviceFormat' parameter, which could have provided the 'format' info. Therefore, I am a bit baffled about how the game got the 'format' info. Could any of the aforementioned calls, indirectly get the 'format' info?

I am using the API monitor application [http://www.rohitab.com/downloads] for my analysis with the 'Audio and Video' filter enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to get the mixer format from `IsFormatSupported`.

```
HRESULT IsFormatSupported(
  [in]        AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE ShareMode,
  [in]  const WAVEFORMATEX      *pFormat,
  [out]       WAVEFORMATEX      **ppClosestMatch //< Audio format suggested by the Windows audio engine
);
```

`IsFormatSupported` is used for format negociation, in Windows you can open an audio format that is different from the mixer format if there is an Audio Processing Object in the audio graph that is able to do the conversion.
But if you provide a `pFormat` that is not the mixer format and there is no available conversion, then Windows will assign the `ppClosestMatch` with an allocated `WAVEFORMATEX` populated with the mixer format.
Here a sample code that I have tested that is able to get the mixer format from `IsFormatSupported` (There is no error handling for simplicity) :

```
CComPtr<IMMDeviceEnumerator> pEnum;
pEnum.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator));
CComPtr<IMMDevice> pDevice;
pEnum->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eMultimedia,&pDevice);
CComPtr<IAudioClient> pAudioClient;
pDevice->Activate( __uuidof(IAudioClient), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&pAudioClient);
// Provide an empty weveformatex
WAVEFORMATEX wfxEmpty = {};
WAVEFORMATEX *pClosestWfx;
HRESULT hr = pAudioClient->IsFormatSupported(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, &wfxEmpty, &pClosestWfx);
if (hr == S_FALSE) {
    // The audio engine suggest us a format in pClosestWfx
    // which is the mixer format because we did not provide a valid input format.
    // the current application did not use any windows API to get the mixer format directly
    // ...
    CoTaskMemFree(pClosestWfx);
}
```

This is another way to get the mixer format.